# Can I use @Synchronized annotation in Kotlin Multiplatform commonMain code?

Tags: kotlin, synchronized, kotlin-multiplatform

Can [@Synchronized](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-synchronized/) annotation be used in common code (`commonMain`) code of Kotlin Multiplatform?
The library only targets JVM and JS.

Will it have any impact on a Kotlin/JS application that calls the `commonMain` code from this library?

When I use @Synchronized in `commonMain`, Intellij shows it is imported from import `kotlin-stdlib-common`; in `jsMain`, it shows imported from `kotlin-stdlib-js`; however, in both the cases, the import statement remains `import kotlin.jvm.Synchronized`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD:**

The `kotlin.jvm.Volatile` annotation has been deprecated for Kotlin/JS and Kotlin/Native, with a warning since Kotlin 1.9. `kotlin.concurrent.Volatile` should be used instead.

---

As indicated in [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-synchronized/), this annotation will only have effect on the JVM method generated from the Kotlin function:

> Marks the JVM method generated from the annotated function as `synchronized`, meaning that the method will be protected from concurrent execution by multiple threads by the monitor of the instance (or, for static methods, the class) on which the method is defined.

In [the sources](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/30788566012c571aa1d3590912468d1ebe59983d/libraries/stdlib/js/src/kotlin/annotationsJVM.kt#L18) of the JS part of the standard library, you can find the following comment about the annotation (along with `@Volatile`), which gives a small hint about its status outside of the JVM:

> ```
> // these are used in common generated code in stdlib
>
> // TODO: find how to deprecate these ones
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your earlier answer. Now these are deprecated
. https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/js/src/kotlin/annotationsJVM.kt